# Почему break предшествует "основному" циклу (python)

Tags: python, for, break

не могли бы вы помочь понять логику в Python.

Есть пример:

```
answers = ["A", "C", "W", "E"]
for x in answers:
    if x == "W":
        print("Wrong")
        break
    print(x)
```

Здесь цикл проходится по всему списку, и если натыкается на ответ "W", то останавливается. На выходе получаем:

```
A
C
Wrong
```

Но я не понимаю, почему сначала идет условие if, а только потом - цикл "проходки" по значениям. Руководствуясь бытовой логикой ведь сначала цикл проходится по значениям, а уже потом должна следовать операция проверки на соответствие значению "W" ? Но если я меняю местами эти две части кода:

```
answers = ["A", "C", "W", "E"]
for x in answers:
    print(x)
    if x == "W":
        print("Wrong")
        break
```

То на выходе имеею:

```
A
C
W
Wrong
```

Не могли бы вы мне помочь разобраться в этой логике?

Comment: Потому что все что внутри цикла for на каждом его "витке" выполняется строго последовательно: сначала проверка, если она срабатывает - то вывод "Wrong" и выход из цикла, если не срабатывает - то только после этого `print(x)`. Если поменять порядок, то естественно сначала будет вывод, потом проверка.

Answer (score 4):

Сначала идет условие if (если W, то завершаем цикл), а потом вывод на печать. А цикл находится  вокруг всего этого. Каждое значение проверяется отдельно.

Вы же сначала ставите вывод на печать, а потом проверку на значение.

Answer (score 2):

Разберем цикл `for`в первом примере на шаги:

1. под проверку попадает "A". Это не "W". Он проходит `if`. Потом он печатает "A"
2. то же самое и с "C".
3. Наступает черед "W". Он проходит `if`. Условие верное - это "W". А в цикле написано: `break`. `break` мгновенно завершает `while`, не проходя последующие действия. А печатать "W" - в последующих действиях.

А вот во втором примере на так. Там печать - не последующее действие. Печать идет перед `break`. И он сначала печатает "W", а потом уже выходит с помощью `break`.